# supersized jquery plugin extra field

Tags: jquery, fullscreen, custom-fields, supersized

Can anyone help show me how to add an extra field to images in supersized jquery plugin?

Currently you have options for the below:

```js
{image : 'IMAGE_PATH', title : 'IMAGE_TITLE', thumb : 'IMAGE_THUMB', url : 'LINK_URL'},
```

I'd like to add two extra fields. Category and Description.

```
{image : 'IMAGE_PATH', title : 'IMAGE_TITLE', thumb : 'IMAGE_THUMB', url : 'LINK_URL', description : 'IMAGE_DESCRIPTION', category : 'IMAGE_CATEGORY'},
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var obj = {image : 'IMAGE_PATH', title : 'IMAGE_TITLE', thumb : 'IMAGE_THUMB', url : 'LINK_URL'}
obj.category = 'IMAGE_CATEGORY';
obj.description = 'DESCRIPTION';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4F2B/2/

Comment: where do you put this and how is it called in the html?

Comment: you should put it in a javascript file, it will be read by js parser, its not a function to be called implicitly.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? I'm fairly new to this and trying to figure it out.